# A Problem in openMP omp for schedule(static,chunk)

Tags: openmp

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int max_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
    ::printf("max threads:%d",max_threads);
    int chunk = 7;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(chunk)
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk)
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; ++i) {
            printf("Thread %d is processing iteration %d\n", thread_id, i);

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Clion with WSL. When I run the code above, the program sometimes meets "Process finished with exit code 010", the code is changing when I run the code.

But when I use `#pragma omp parallel default(none) firstprivate(chunk)`, the program ends with "Process finished with exit code 0".

Thank you for your help.I am a beginner in this field.

I run many times.The exit code is always changing.

Comment: I found even if I use "#pragma omp parallel default(none) firstprivate(chunk)",“Process finished with exit code xxx” will apear. xxx is not "0". Why?

Comment: I find that your code runs fine with both g++ and icx on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/cdTse71vK